# Click event function gets triggered on whole document

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, dom-events

I am trying to close an element only if it has been opened on click but on every click the close function(**ClickedOut(event)**) gets triggered after the popup has been opened once, even when the element is already closed.

Click on any box the popup will open , then click anywhere the popup element closes whereas the objective is once the popup opens on click of the box, popup element should only be closed when clicked outside of the popup element.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7edvms?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
<div (click)="ClickedOut($event)">

<div class="box1" (mouseenter)="addClickEvent($event)" 
(mouseleave)="addClickEvent($event)" (click)="addClickEvent($event)">
 On click
</div>

<div class="box2" (mouseenter)="addClickEvent($event)" 
(mouseleave)="addClickEvent($event)" (click)="addClickEvent($event)">
 On click
</div>


<fs-modal *ngIf="opened" [ngStyle]="modalStyleClikedFlag ? modelClickedStyle 
:modelStyle" (mouseleave)="onPopEvent($event)">
</fs-modal>

</div>
```

TS file

```
export class AppComponent {
  modelStyle: any = {
    display: 'none'
  };
  modelClickedStyle: any = {
    display: 'none'
  };

  modalStyleClikedFlag;
  opened;

addClickEvent(e) {
    let x = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
 if (e.type === 'click') {
    this.modalStyleClikedFlag = true;
    this.modelClickedStyle = {
    top: 0 + 'px',
    left: 0 + 'px',
    height: 900 + 'px',
    width: 90 + '%',
    display: 'block'
   };
    this.opened = false;
   }
else if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
    this.opened = true;
    this.modalStyleClikedFlag = false;
    if(((window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) - 
    x.right) >200 ){
    this.modelStyle = {
            top: 0 + 'px',
            left: x.right + 'px',
            height: screen.height + 'px',
            width: 65 +'%',
            display: 'flex'
            };
            }else{
            this.modelStyle = {
            top: 0 + 'px',
            right : ((window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth)
           - x.left)
             + 'px',
            height: screen.height + 'px',
            width: 65 +'%',
            display: 'flex'
            };

        }
}
else if (e.type === 'mouseleave' && e.clientX < x.right) {
  this.modelStyle = {
    display: 'none'
  };
}
}

onPopEvent() {
  this.modelStyle = {
   display: 'none'
 };
}

ClickedOut(event): void {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.opened = !this.opened
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because a child will always get the click event from the parent : it's called event bubbling and you can find several ways of stopping it online.

What you can do to prevent it :

```
<fs-modal *ngIf="opened" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" ... >
```